# how to insert and iframe from php

Tags: php, iframe

I have create a form, after details have been submitted I am trying to open an Iframe for the response. But I keep receiving an error in the line in bold.
 This is my code:

// this code is within my php code

```
if($result){
**echo <li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="datasave.php" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>**
}
else{
echo"ERROR"
}
```

datasave.php  ==>  This is the code in this file

```
<?php
echo Your details have been sent successfully!;
?>
```

Comment: Syntax error, unexpected

Comment: unexpected what? And also, why are you using ** infront of the echo and after? you are also missing a ; at your `echo"ERRO"` (it should be: `echo"ERROR";`

Comment: Parse error: syntax on line 18

Answer (score 1):

Either:

Leave PHP mode if you want to go into output mode. You can't just put raw HTML where PHP is expected.

```
if($result){
?>
    <li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="datasave.php" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>
<?php
}
```

**or**

Put delimiters (`"` or `'` usually) around your PHP strings.

```
if($result){
    echo '<li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="datasave.php" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The error is gone.
Maybe I did not explain myself well. The iframe is no opening in the same page that the form is still goes to a new page

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your this line

```
**echo <li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="datasave.php" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>**
```

with this one

```
echo '<li><iframe width="420" height="315" src="datasave.php" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>';
```